# Pronunciation problem with "park" and "walk". Is there a name for this "phenomenon"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, speech

Now and then, I struggle to say a pair of words such as "park and walk".  It may come out as "park and wark" or "pork and walk".  It occurs generally when the two words are close together in a sentence.

Is there a name for this behaviour or speech idiosyncrasy or is it unrecognised officially?  I know there is [rhotacism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotacism), which is the recognised mis-pronunciation of the letter, "r".

Is there a name for my "affliction"?

Some other examples:

- War and car
- Far and talk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The technical term is ***Dissimilation***, usually. There are more technical variants, depending on the details of individual variations and habits. *Dissimilation* is an opposite of ***Assimilation***; both are Latin words, describing the processes of (respectively) 'becoming **less** similar' and 'becoming **more** similar'.

Similar in **sound**, in this case. Both processes are normal phonological phenomena, due to the realities of pronouncing certain sequences of sounds, and both are often the source of historical changes.

**Assimilation** is the reason why there's a **P** in *assumption*, for instance — the voiceless dental stop /t/ (back in Latin, where it was actually /t/ instead of /ʃ/ like English) assimilates its beginning to the preceding labial nasal /m/, producing an unavoidable voiceless labial stop /p/, whether it's spelled or not.

**Dissimilation**, on the other hand, changes one or more of several identical sounds that come close together but are separated by other sounds. Phonemes like retroflex /r/ and lateral /l/, which are similar in production, are difficult to pronounce in sequence but easy to alternate between, so they are particularly prone to this in European languages:

- the pronunciation of *colonel* dissimilates the first /l/ to an /r/ (but keeps the spelling).
- *marble* comes from Latin *marmora*, where the second /r/ has dissimilated to an /l/ (and the second /m/ has dissimilated to a /b/).
- The German verb 'to murmur' is *murmeln*, where the second /r/ has dissimilated to /l/.

Then there are all kinds of productive dissimilations, like

> "Factors, schmactors! What's the bottom line?",

or dissimilative reduplications, like *pitter-patter, mishmosh,* or *repple-depple;* and even fully-dissimilated (though no longer productive) derivational morphemes, like the adjective-forming suffix in [this puzzle](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Latin_dissimilation.pdf).

Comment: The p in _assumption_ is not really assimilation—it's excrescence (which is assimilative by nature). The first s in _assumption_ is true assimilation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a frequent type of mispronunciation, where one speech sound occurs too early or too late. If a sound is produced too early, i.e., the error occurs before the source, then it is called an anticipatory error ("pork and walk", anticipation of vowel sound). If the error occurs after the source, then it is called a perseveration ("park and wark", perseveration of /r/). These errors typically occur if the source and error sounds and syllables are phonetically similar, i.e. they share several features and differ in only a few features, and if the two syllables involved are not too far apart (a span of 7 syllables has been suggested) as in your examples.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_error
and references listed there.